# xcode debugger does not show values

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

Xcode 7.2.1. debugger does not show values. I am not sure when it started, probably with Xcode upgrade.

[image]

Searched same issues on SOF , and found only old Q&A.

Anyway, most of answers are suggesting to check if i'm in Release or Debug mode. I tried every suggestion and nothing helps.

I reinstalled Xcode - nothing.
Btw, i started new blank project, and Xcode shows all variables properly.

I use a .XCworkspace , and same picture in my old .Xcodeproj

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check in Project `Build Settings` > `Optimization Level`. Debug should be set to None, is it?

Comment: yes, sure, that is the most usual advice...

Comment: Can you print them out? `po myVariable`?

Comment: Have you tried deleting `Derived Data` and cleaning build folder (both with and without options pressed)?

Comment: I tried po SomeVariable. nothing happened - no error, no reply)

Comment: @sschale , how I do this?

Comment: For Derived Data, navigate to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode` and delete the DerivedData folder. To clean, go to menu Product -> Clean, and do it again with options held down.

Comment: i deleted Derived Data , no changes. no values, no "self" disclosure...

Comment: tried "po someVariable" (opened debugger output)  - got : error: Error in auto-import:
failed to get module 'myProject' from AST context

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a couple of months, and same thing, I searched and found those usual answers about making sure you're in Debug mode, making sure Optimization Level was set to "None" for debug, etc.

Today I fixed it! And I don't know exactly how. But I went through the Build Settings in my Target, removing any settings I had specific to the *Target* and instead setting them to be specific to the *Project*. I don't know which one it was that fixed it, but I swear it worked!